# jQuery event handler wont activate on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get my fizzbuzzz solution to run on "click" and display inbetween code tags in a container but nothing is printing out when I click inside the div and I can't figure out why.

For my function I have :

```
function fizzbuzz(){
    for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++){
        if ((i % 15) === 0) {
            console.log('FizzBuzz');
            } else if ((i % 3) === 0){
            console.log('Fizz');
            } else if ((i % 5) === 0){
            console.log('Buzz');
            } else {
            console.log(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

for my index.html view  I have this :

```
  <div id="results" class="container text-center">
    <p>Click to view the results of the function we just wrote: </p>
    <code></code>
  </div>
```

and for my jQuery script I have :

```
$("#results").click(function() {
  fizzbuzz();
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I will greatly appreciate any feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, there's no special meaning for `<code>` tags, and nothing you're doing would put code in there. What you're likely looking for is something closer to this:

```
<div id="results" class="container text-center">
    <p>Click to view the results of the function we just wrote: </p>
    <span id="fizzbuzz"></span>
</div>
```

with the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function fizzbuzz(){
    elt = $('#fizzbuzz'); // find the element
    elt.empty(); // clear out anything that's there already
    for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++){
        if ((i % 15) === 0) {
            elt.append('FizzBuzz'); // append text
            } else if ((i % 3) === 0){
            elt.append('Fizz');
            } else if ((i % 5) === 0){
            elt.append('Buzz');
            } else {
            elt.append(i);
            }
        elt.append(" "); // add a space
        }
    }

$("#results").click(function() { // use .click(... or .on('click'..., not .onClick
  fizzbuzz();
});
});
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know you could place a function in a span like that! Brilliant! Thanks I definitely learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

.onClick is wrong.  Use .click instead: (http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$("#results").click(function() {
  fizzbuzz();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I tried this and it did not work. Is there an issue with the html perhaps? I never tried to use jQuery on a div before. I just did it with a submit button in the past.

Comment: Refer to @Christian's response for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try

```
$("#results").on('click', function() {
    fizzbuzz();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I tried this and it did not work. Is there an issue with the html perhaps? I never tried to use jQuery on a div before. I just did it with a submit button in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If that fails you could try:

```
$("#results").bind('click', function() {
    fizzbuzz();
});
```